# How to generate ipa file without xcode from windows? if possible

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I am trying to create ipa without mac and xcode. I have iphone to test app. I never used expo for development purpose. Is this possible with expo or any online resource which can generate this ipa for testing purpose only? Its a React native app

Comment: in which language your code is written ??
in `angular` or `swift` or `objc`  or `c#`??

Comment: "javascript" I think i forget to mention app is developed using React Native

Answer (score 1):

Yes it'll be possible with [Expo](https://expo.io/).

You need to create a new project with [`create-react-native-app`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) or [`exp init`](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/exp-cli.html), then move your existing code over and execute `exp build:ios`, which will build the `ipa` on Expo's servers for you to download.

You will not be able to include any third party native libraries (i.e. libraries that aren't 100% Javascript, that you had to link with `react-native link`).

However, Expo provides an [extensive list of native API](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/) for you to use.

Comment: it will be great if you provide a direct link to expo documentation.

Comment: I did, all the blue text are clickable links.